# Parse .ETL file in Azure Web Job

Tags: c#, azure, logging, etl, azure-webjobs

I have a bunch of .ETL crash files stored in Azure blob storage that I want to parse and store in a SQL table.  So far the only way I've found to parse these .ETL files is to pass them into `tracerpt` and then parse the XML file outputted from `tracerpt`.

I'm assuming that I can't access `tracerpt` from an Azure Web Job.  If I can, what do I need to call to get access to that .EXE? Are there any pure code solutions for parsing .ETL trace files?

The .ETL files are made from a `LoggingSession` object in a Windows Store App.

Comment: Why the -1?  I feel like this is a valid question?

Comment: have you tried running `tracerpt` from the [debug console](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Kudu-console)? Browse to `https://<yourSiteName>.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole` and then you'll have a cmd-like web interface, you can drag and drop an etl file into a folder from the file explorer above then test `tracerpt` and see if it works or not. This is the same environment that runs your webjobs so if it works from that cmd, it'll work from a webjob

Comment: I actually ended up using the ETW2JSON NuGet package.  Now I work with JSON instead of ETW :)  Much easier to work with

Comment: can you share a link? It doesn't show up in Nuget search for me.

Comment: http://www.nuget.org/packages/ETW2JSON/ is the link.  I also read through the code to get familiar with what it was doing... Yeah, lots of PInvoking...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using http://www.nuget.org/packages/ETW2JSON/ to do the parsing into JSON and then I did my data analytics from there.